# What is the precedence of conditions in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL. I have a table called instructor with id,name,dept_name,salary as the attributes. I have written a query to 'find all the instructors whose salary is greater than at least one instructor in the Physics department' as

```
select t.name, t.dept_name, t.salary
from instructor t, instructor s
where t.salary > s.salary and s.dept_name='physics';
```

Now which condition will be applied first?

Comment: There is no question of precedence here. There is an order-of-evaluation question, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @EJP ,Can u tell me how the records will be compared here? Whether each record in 't' with those in 's' or in some other way.

Answer (score 2):

The entire `WHERE` condition will be applied, meaning that in order for a record to appear in the result set it will have to meet both the salary and department requirements.

You query looks almost correct, except that you probably want to include `DISTINCT` to make sure you don't report the same instructor more than once in your result set:

```
select distinct t.name, t.dept_name, t.salary
from instructor t
inner join instructor s
    on t.salary > s.salary and s.dept_name='physics'
```

You will notice that I have also replaced your implicit join syntax with an explicit `inner join`.  You should avoid putting commas into the `from` clause, as this is a very old school way of doing a join which is considered deprecated by modern RDBMS.

Comment: "if the first condition (salary check) fails, then MySQL might skip checking the second condition." --- this is simply wrong. There is no notion of order of predicates in mysql (and any other mature RDBMS)

Comment: @zerkms I didn't know this as in most programming languages the order of the logic is preserved in things like an `if` statement.  Knowing that there is an order to evaluation can be useful in many cases.

Comment: "Knowing that there is an order to evaluation can be useful in many cases" --- not in case of DBMS. Database knows more than you and can make a better decision on how to evaluate the query.

Comment: I'd edit to say *you should never put commas into the `from` clause* instead. :-)

Comment: Just an edit consideration... the "t" alias person is also in the physics department... probably want AND NOT t.dept_name='physics'

Comment: @DRapp Actually, the check should be that the primary keys from the `instructor` tables do not match.  But checking that the salary is greater than the other should ensure that an instructor cannot count himself.

Comment: @Tim, my point is that they are looking for greater than at least 1 person in Physics dept.  So, if you have 20 teachers and two physics teachers, all with different salaries, then you are guaranteed that one physics teacher has a higher salary than the other, thus qualifying his question.  I THINK they want teachers from OTHER DEPARTMENTS that have a salary higher than any one from physics department.  Not to be complaining, just clarifying my interpretation of what they might MEAN they want, not what they are asking... :)

Comment: @DRapp I understand your logic now, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can u tell me how the records will be compared here? Whether each record in 't' with those in 's' or in some other way.

Comment: @BabyboB If you look at the comments by @zerkms above, there is no guaranteed order of evaluation to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim mentioned in his answer, the entire where criteria is considered.  I also commented to him that I think what you are asking for are instructors from other departments that have a salary greater than anyone in the physics dept.  If you have 3 people in physics, all with different salaries, then two people have salaries greater than the lowest paid physics, but all 3 could be higher than everyone else at the school.

This would be better handled with a subquery to find the lowest physics dept salary first, then look for anyone greater than that value...

Also, the way you have it, you are going to have a Cartesian comparison since there is no JOIN condition.  Every record in the instructor table is compared to every record in the SECOND instructor table (including the record it is being compared to.)

To resolve this, the second from alias below is precalculating the lowest salary ONCE for the physics department, then applying that ONE answer to all other instructor salaries that are NOT in the physics department.

```
select 
      t.name, 
      t.dept_name, 
      t.salary
   from 
      instructor t,
      ( select min( ps.salary ) PhysicsLowest
           from instructor ps
           where ps.dept_name='physics' ) as Phys
   where
          t.salary > Phys.PhysicsLowest
      AND NOT t.dept_name = 'physics'
```